# set theory forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Suppose $M$ satisfies the $CH$ and that we force over $M$ with $\mathbb{P}=Fn(I,2)$ where  $(\omega_{2} \leq |I|))^{M}$, that is, with the finite partial functions from $I$ to $2$. If $f \in M[G] \cap \omega^{\omega}$, then is there necessarily a function $g \in M \cap \omega^{\omega}$ for which {$n:f(n) \leq g(n)$} is infinite?
Please give a suggestion to help me work this exercise from Kunen's book.

Comment: Your question uses unexplained notation, mentions an exercise in a book but does not tell us what excercise nor what book, and it is quite not clear what you are trying to ask. 

Comment: The question is completely clear. This is a graduate-level question about forcing, using completely standard notation and terminology. It seems fine for MO. 

Comment: I believe you are asking why Cohen forcing doesn't add dominating reals.  A proof of this fact can in the Bartoszynski-Judah book "Set theory of the real line".

Comment: No Joel, the question is not clear. There is in fact no question, and the sentences are hard to parse. We can sort of see what a possible question could perhaps be, given what is written, but that is a different story.

Comment: Andres, what isn't clear? He wants to know if every function $f:\omega\to\omega$ added by the forcing $Fn(I,2)$ when $\omega_2\leq|I|$ does not dominate some ground model $g:\omega\to\omega$. Clearly the English could be improved, but the mathematical question seems clear. In my opinion, the downvotes and votes to close are not appropriate.

Comment: I tend to side with Joel. I think the appropriate reaction is to edit the question. (This is not done enough on MO!)

Comment: François, I have edited.

Comment: (Any further discussion should probably happen in a meta thread)

Comment: I think part of the question was also whether the assumption on the size of I or CH were necessary.

Comment: Joel's editing has produced a reasonable question, which might or might not be what the OP intended.  

Comment: Well, Miguel, despite the closure of your question, I'd like to welcome you to MathOverflow. I'm truly very sorry to see a newcomer get such a rough reception. I know that this could be discouraging, but I'd like to encourage you not to become discouraged. Please try to look past it and simply try again with other questions! Indeed, you seem to be studying forcing, and I'd particularly encourage questions on forcing, which is definitely on-topic here at MO. You may find that you will get a more favorable reception with a more carefully worded question or fuller explanation. 

Comment: Miguel, I too feel that this sort of question is a good fit for MO. However as with all other exercises which appear on this site, the level of the question must be above average. It should reflect the fact that you put quite an effort into the question before coming here. In either case I have voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a sketch of a proof:  Let $\dot f$ be a name for $f$.  Wlog we may assume that 
$\dot f$ is a nice name and hence uses only countably many conditions.
It follows that it is an $Fn(J,2)$-name for some countable set $J\subseteq I$.
Let $(p_n)_{n\in\omega}$ be an enumeration of $Fn(J,2)$.

We construct a function $g\in M$ as follows.
For each $n\in\omega$ choose $g(n)$ such that for all $k\leq n$ the following holds:
if for some $m\in\omega$ we have $p_k\Vdash\dot f(n)\gt m$, then $g(n)\gt m$.
It is possible to choose $g(n)$ in this way since for all $p\in Fn(J,2)$ there are only finitely many $m$ such that $p\Vdash\dot f(n)\gt m$.

We show that $g$ has the desired property.  Suppose this is not the case.
Let $p\in G$ and $n_0\in\omega$ be such that $$p\Vdash\forall n\geq n_0(\dot f(n)\gt g(n)).$$
For some $k\in\omega$, $p=p_k$.  Now let $n\geq n_0,k$.  Then $p_k\Vdash\dot f(n)\gt m$
for $m=g(n)$.  By the choice of $g$, $g(n)\gt m=g(n)$, a contradiction.